# JSLint : Expected '!!' and instead saw '?'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am getting the error in the question mark. Here is the code

```
var isParallelStage = ($("#workflowStagesList .workflowStageListItemActive").find("p").text() === "P") ? true : false;
```

Error:

> JSLint : Expected '!!' and instead saw '?'.

Comment: `var isParallelStage = $("#workflowStagesList .workflowStageListItemActive")
.find("p").text() === "P"` should do the work for you, You don't need conditional operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`? true : false` is an antipattern - it's totally useless, an identity function, you can simply omit it, you've already got a boolean. And if you didn't, you should use `!!` or `Boolean(…)` to cast your value to a boolean.

Comment: If possible, Can you able to provide any sample to use !!.

Comment: @shankar.siva: Instead of `x ? true : false`, write `!!x`.

Comment: How do we set this. isAuthorStep ? "Author" : "";

Comment: @shankar.siva There's nothing you need to do about that code?