# jslint expected !! and instead saw?

Tags: javascript, jslint

Now before anyone links this article:
[JSLint : Expected '!!' and instead saw '?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770789/jslint-expected-and-instead-saw)

I want to explain that I think I understand why jslint is giving me this error, however I am unsure as to how I would rework the line of code below to utilise the !! operator.

```
active = $item.find('isActive').text() === 'true' ? true : false,
```

Would someone mind enlightening me on this?

I tried doing this first but even to my novice eyes I could see this was basically nonsense :

```
active = $item.find('isActive').text() === !! 'true' true : false,
```

I want to write clean javascript so i'd rather get a proper explanation as to why using !! instead of ? is good practice. Looking on the JSLint errors site didn't shed any light on this sadly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am unsure as to how I would rework the line of code below to utilise the !! operator.

You wouldn't in this case, neither `!!` nor `? :` is appropriate here. `===` evaluates to a boolean, so simply:

```
active = $item.find('isActive').text() === 'true'
```

All of the equality operators (`===`, `!==`, `==`, `!=`) and relational operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) result in true booleans.

**If** you wanted to set `active` to a boolean value based on whether something was *truthy* (coerces to `true`) or *falsy* (coerces to `false`) *then* `!!` would be appropriate. But not when you already have a boolean.

For instance, suppose you want to set `blank` based on whether `str` is falsy. In that case,

```
blank = !!str
```

would be reasonable.

Comment: I guess he's trying to something totally different.

Comment: aha i see! so basically the jslint error kinda led me down the rabbit hole on that one :P Thanks for the help buddy :D